# IBM Quantum Lab - Server unavailable or unreachable. Would you like to restart?

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, state-tomography

In the following circuit, I want to perform tomography on the qubits 0,1,2,3 after qubits 4,5,6,7,8,9 are measured.

[image: Circuit]

I run the circuit using with measurement gates on qubits 4,5,6,7,8,9 with the following code:

```
backend = QasmSimulator()
backend_options = {'method': 'statevector'}
job = qiskit.execute(circuit, backend, backend_options=backend_options, shots = 1)
job_result = job.result()
state_vector = job_result.get_statevector(circuit)
```

After that, I run tomography on the statevector I obtain in the above code.

Following the official [tutorial](https://qiskit.org/documentation/experiments/tutorials/state_tomography.html), I perform tomography using this:

```
from qiskit_experiments.library import StateTomography

qstexp1 = StateTomography(state_vector, measurement_qubits = [0,1,2,3])
qstdata1 = qstexp1.run(backend, seed_simulation=100).block_for_results().
```

But the tomography code runs for a long time and then I get the message

> Server unavailable or unreachable. Would you like to restart?

I am running this code on IBM Quantum Lab.

What am I doing wrong here? Is this too big a state vector to be doing tomography on?
And is my approach of first simulating the full circuit and then using the posterior statevector for tomography correct?

Comment: QasmSimulator doesn't generate state vector result, you should consider using StatevectorSimulator or AerSimulator.

Comment: your question has a lot of errors, please review them, and edit the question.

Comment: for the `Server unavailable or unreachable. Would you like to restart?` it is Jupiter notebook, try to follow instruction: https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/lab/docs/iql/troubleshooting#reset-your-notebook-pod.       
related Jupyter Discourse Forum: https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/server-unavailable-or-unreachable-error-in-jupyterlab/13071
related github issue: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/9324

Comment: I changed to AerSimulator and I am able to run tomography. Thank You